# File not found exception. What could go wrong?

Tags: java, file, exception

I declared a file's path before `main` :

```
  static String filePath = "C:\\file.rdf";
```

Then I created File from this path within the `main`:

```
File file=new File(filePath);
```

Then I called a function with arguments that one of them is this particular file:
`parser.parseFile(file, subsetDenom,skew,topicPattern);`

However, when I run my code, I get the FileNotFundException.
What could be go wrong?

```
 static String filePath = "C:\\file.rdf";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file=new File(filePath);

      parser.parseFile(file, subsetDenom,skew,
          topicPattern);
}
  public void parseFile(File file, int subsetDenom, int skew, Pattern topicPattern){
 XMLCharFilter in = new XMLCharFilter(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            file)), "UTF-8"))); //gives exception here  
   }
```

Comment: The very first tag you should add to a code-related question is for the language you're using.

Comment: The file simply doesn't exist on your server.

Comment: @ydoow It does. I have checked it many times.

Comment: @e4c5 My bad. I fixed it.

Comment: @KenWhite My bad, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your filePath String is likely wrong. Have you checked that you are using the correct syntax (slashes, double-slashes, etc.)?

Comment: it is not. when I use `sout` right after the file deceleration, it shows the path but then later in the function, it gives that exception. Moreover, the path is really simple like `C:\\filename`

Comment: Just because you can print a String does not mean the value of the String is correct. You did not provide the info before.

Comment: now I did. But if the path was wrong, it had to give the exception before going into the function.

Comment: Tried to reduce your code to the minimum like: File file = File("C:\\abc.txt");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();